# Deleted multiple users from site collection using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016

I need to perform a bulk delete for multiple users in the SharePoint site collection using PowerShell Script!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** you should specify which users should you delete

**Second,** you can for each user in the user list as the following:

```
$usersToDelete = @()

foreach ($user in $usersToDelete)
{
    $Site.RootWeb.SiteUsers.Remove($user);
}
```

Check the full script at [Delete Users from SharePoint Site Collection using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/delete-users-from-site-collection-using-powershell.html#ixzz4q1ncRI1w)

---

**See also**

- [Bulk Delete SharePoint Site Users with PowerShell](https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/bulk-delete-sharepoint-site-users-with-powershell/)
- [PowerShell script to remove all users from a SharePoint Group](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijgang/2009/04/26/powershell-script-to-remove-all-users-from-a-sharepoint-group/)